# How do you set up the database Queue driver for Laravel 5?

Tags: php, database, laravel, queue, laravel-5

I am building an application with Laravel that receives notifications and then fires events to handle those notifications. I want these events to be Queued so that only one event is handled at a time.

I've been trying to use the "database" Queue driver that the documentation says is available. I've changed the default driver in config/queue.php so it is set to use "database" and I ran php artisan queue:table to create the jobs migration but when I send a notification to the app I do not see any sign of queues being used in the jobs table or anywhere else. What could be going wrong?

(My EventHandler class is using ShouldBeQueued as well)

Comment: Are you running `php artisan queue:listen` before firing the queued event? Check out the answer I gave to your other question.

Comment: Yes, it turned out Laravel wasn't grabbing the database QUEUE_DRIVER from my .env file for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: https://tivbroc.com/en/laravel-5-how-to-setup-queues-and-keep-them-running/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your **.env** file, you have to add this.

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```